# How to run a java program with selenium jar through command line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to run a java program with selenium jar through command line...

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HelloSelenium {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver;

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

}
```

I am getting following error on running it through CLI

> java -cp ".;./jars/selenium-java-2.53.0.jar" HelloSelenium

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
    at HelloSelenium.main(HelloSelenium.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify the classpath explicitly, the current directory is not included by default. So you should do

```
java -cp selenium-java-2.53.0.jar;. HelloSelenium
```

Note the extra ";.", e.g. adding . to classpath.

This will still be insufficient, however, as selenium itself has many other libraries as dependencies (included in the libs folder of your download). You will need to add those to your classpath as well.

Easiest to add them all with a wildcard for your simple example. So you should use:

```
java -cp selenium-java-2.53.0.jar;libs/*;. HelloSelenium
```

Note the "libs/*", which assumes you are in the root folder of your selenium download.